# How to create a buttonlistener for an inflated button

Tags: android

Am quite new to Android programming and hope someone can help me out in this:
1. I am coding from one of the demos here:
    http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

1. I have a main activity_screen_slide.xml file:

   `<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>`
2. In another xml file, main.xml, I have a few buttons.

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/Main"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
   <Button
   android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
   android:text="test"/>
   </LinearLayout>`

Within the main java activity file, the context is set as following:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);
```

When I tried to set a listener for testButton, am unable to do so. This means that when the button is generated subsequently (through an inflator in another java file), there is no response when I click the button.

The java file to generate the inflator is simply:

```
ViewGroup rootView;
rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
```

Thank you and appreciate your help

Cheers
D

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Can you post the code where you try to set the `listener`?

Comment: After you inflate `main.xml` to be `rootView` you can use `rootView.findViewById(...)` to find any of the buttons (or other widgets) that have been inflated.

Comment: Button buttonStartRun = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);buttonStartRun.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: You are trying to inflate it in one `Activity` and use it in another? If so, that won't work.

Comment: Hi codeMagic, I am trying to inflate it in one java class but then the button is not preset in the main xml file where the context is being set. I realized that the code for the xml is not being displayed. Let me try to post that code again.

Comment: We really need a more comprehensive code snippet to fully understand what you are doing. I'm confused where the problem is. Does the `Button` get initialized? Does the `onClickListener` just not respond?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your button is defined in your xml layout **activity_screen_slide.xml** similar to this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

In your Activity you can add a ClickListener like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("", "I've been clicked");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Mirco, thank you for your reply.

Yes, the button is set in that manner.

The issue here is that the xml file container the button is within main.xml. The button from main.xml will be called out in another class by inflation. Hence this method will not be able to find the id of the button.

Comment: why would you want to use the button specified for activity a use in activity b?

Comment: its in the same activity. but different xml file. So I am using a ViewGroup to store multiple xml files and trying to inflate them one at a time. However they are all in the same activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Settings extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...ALL THE OTHER CODE..\\
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
     @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID: {

            ALPHA.YourFunction(parameters);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Stefano, Thank you for your reply. I tried doing this in the main activity class originally. Let me try doing this in the class where the button is being inflated

Comment: Ok i got the problem. Why are you trying to use a button in another activity? Every activity has its own buttons. Inflate can be useful for example when you start a dialog over the activity!

Comment: Hmm.. perhaps my concept of activity and class is flawed. Do educate me on this. The flow is in this manner. Activity x sets context to be y. After that it instantiates a class alpha which inflates beta. The button I am trying to set a listener to is in beta. I am trying to set the listener in x. Hope this clarifies things or did I get everything all mixed up?

Comment: Maybe you want call a function in beta, when a button in alpha is pressed? Let me understand

Comment: Hi Stefano, sorry that I might have been unclear earlier. X and alpha are java classes. X is the main activity. Y and beta are xml files. To clarify your answer, do you mean to say that I am unable to call a function from x when a button in beta is being pressed?

Comment: In X you can call a function from ALPHA doing `ALPHA.NameOfTheFunction();` if the function has appropriate visibility (so not private). This is what you want? Let me understand better :)

Comment: Hi Stefano, Thank you for your reply. Actually what I need is that a function from either X or ALPHA gets called when the button is pressed. The issue I am facing is that nothing gets called when the button is pressed =)

Comment: Hi Stefano, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, the onClick function is not even called.. haha...

Comment: WHy not? Are you sure you're using some ID to associate an then in the onClick method?

Comment: Hi Stefano, Thank you for your help. In the end I pushed the button listener to the ALPHA java class and not in the X java class. After that using rootView.findViewById(...) to find the individual IDs (as suggested by Squonk above) Thanks!